# Java using multiple logger types in the same file skipping log statements

Tags: java, maven, osgi, java.util.logging, apache-commons-logging

There is an maven OSGI component in which I have a call to `EclipseStarter.stop()` statement which shuts down the OSGI framework. There are a couple of log statements printed after this line. I have used pax-logging with log4j2 as the logging backend and JCL at the frontend.

Since OSGI framework is down the log messages do not print through pax-logging-log4j2. Therefore I am trying to use java util logging to print these messages. The logger initialization in the java file is done as follows.

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

log.info("Before shutdown");

EclipseStarter.stop();

logger.log(Level.INFO, "After shutdown JUL");    
log.info("After shutdown JCL");
```

The util logging statement seems to be skipping when I debugged.

Comment: Did you verify that there are handlers attached to `MyClass` logger, parents of `MyClass` logger or root logger?

Comment: Looks like it doesnt. handlers.publish(record) in method log(Record) is skipped.

Comment: Attach a handler.  Add a JUL log statement before the `stop` call too to aid in debugging.

Comment: Adding handlers again programatically worked. Thank you for the suggestion. You can add it as the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see output from a logger you have to attach a [`Handler` subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html).  You can add them from [code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler-java.util.logging.Handler-) or you can create a [`logging.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).